# C++ Not able to read a file using a member functon after initializing

Tags: c++, ifstream, file-read

I have a large patient database file that I have to read and operate on it.
 I am using the below code to do that, by seting `db_nm` to the file name `./testing.db` and then calling the member function read_db.

But I am making some mistake that I am unable to identify. I get the: `std::cout << "Error:Unable to read the DB file..." << std::endl;` as the program cannot seem to open my file for reading.

What am I doing wrong? I am new to CPP.

Thanks.
Vic

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>


class PatientData {
    private:
        std::string db_file;

    public:
        PatientData(std::string db_file);
        void read_db(void);
};

PatientData::PatientData(std::string db_file) {
    db_file = db_file;
}

void PatientData::read_db(void) {
    std::string db = db_file;
    std::fstream fs;
    std::string line;
    fs.open(db, std::ios_base::in); 
    if (!fs) {
        std::cout << "Error:Unable to read the DB file..." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Processing DB file " << db << "..." << std::endl; 
    }
    fs.close();
}

int main() {
    std::string db_nm   =  "./testing.db";

    PatientData ptdb(db_nm);
    ptdb.read_db();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A quick fix could be `this>db_file = db_file;` but for a constructor you should learn to use the initializer list. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Answer (score 1):

Your issue probably lies in the ambiguity that can be found in the `PatientData` constructor: what does `db_file` stand for ? The class attribute or the method's parameter ?

A quick fix would be to give the argument anothe name such as:

```cpp
PatientData::PatientData(std::string filename){
    db_file = filename;
}
```

If this does not solve your problem, then check the value of `db_file` at the beginning of `read_db` and make sure that the file does exist and is reachable from the current working directory.

Answer (score -2):

You could to check `is_open()` method to know if opening worked or not.
See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/is_open/

Fix:

```
fs.open(db, std::ios_base::in); 
if (!fs.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "Error:Unable to read the DB file..." << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Processing DB file " << db << "..." << std::endl; 
}
fs.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Xatyrian. I've fixed my answer. I have always used `is_open()`